# Ansible command module, creates not being observed

Tags: ansible

I have a module which will install some plugins in an application:

```
- name: install plugins
  command: "some_command install-plugin {{ item }}"
  creates: "/var/lib/application/plugins/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - plugin1
    - plugin2
    - plugin3
```

Im expect that if `/var/lib/application/plugins/plugin[123]` exists, then the command will NOT be run, however it is. Everytime.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have seen this error:

> ERROR! 'creates' is not a valid attribute for a Task

[args](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-execute-commands-on-targets) keyword is missing. Correct syntax is

```
- name: install plugins
  command: "some_command install-plugin {{ item }}"
  args:
    creates: "/var/lib/application/plugins/{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - plugin1
    - plugin2
    - plugin3
```

[loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-list) is recommended instead of with_items.

Comment: Didnt see the error message, but that was exactly it. Thanks so much